# React Hook who refer to DOM element return "null" on first call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have got an hook who catch `getBoundingClientRect` object of a ref DOM element. The problem is, at the first render, it return `null` and I need to get the value only on first render on my component.

I use it like that in a functional component:

```
const App = () => {

  // create ref 
  const rootRef = useRef(null);

  // get Client Rect of rootRef 
  const refRect = useBoundingClientRect(rootRef);

  useEffect(()=> {
    // return "null" the first time
    // return "DOMRect" when refRect is update
    console.log(refRect)
  }, [refRect])

  return <div ref={rootRef} >App</div>

}
```

Here the useBoundingClientRect hook, I call in App Component.

```
export function useBoundingClientRect(pRef) {

  const getBoundingClientRect = useCallback(() => {
    return pRef && pRef.current && pRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  }, [pRef]);

  const [rect, setRect] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRect(getBoundingClientRect());
  },[]);

  return rect;
}
```

The problem is I would like to cache boundingClientRect object on init and not the second time component is rerender :

```
  // App Component

  useEffect(()=> {
    // I would like to get boundingClientRect the 1st time useEffect is call.
    console.log(refRect)

  // empty array allow to not re-execute the code in this useEffect
  }, [])
```

I've check few tutorials and documentations and finds some people use `useRef` instead of `useState` hook to keep value. So I tried to use it in my `useboundingClientRect` hook to catch and return the boundingClientRect value on the first render of my App component. And it works... partially:

```
export function useBoundingClientRect(pRef) {

  const getBoundingClientRect = useCallback(() => {
    return pRef && pRef.current && pRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
  }, [pRef]);

  const [rect, setRect] = useState(null);

  // create a new ref
  const rectRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setRect(getBoundingClientRect());

    // set value in ref
    const rectRef = getBoundingClientRect()

  },[]);

  //  return rectRef for the first time 
  return rect === null ? rectRef : rect;
}
```

Now the `console.log(rectRef)` in App Component allow to access the value on first render:

```
   // App Component

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(refRect.current)
  }, [])
```

But If I try to return `refRect.current` from `useBoundingClientRect` hook return `null`. (What?!)

if anyone can explain theses mistakes to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const rectRef = ` doesnt set anything. it creates another local variable. `rectRef.value =` is what you are looking for ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand references, mututation, and the asynchronous nature of updates here.

Firstly, when you use state to store the `clientRect` properties when your custom hook in `useEffect` runs, it sets value in state which will reflect in the next render cycle since state updates are asynchronous. This is why on first render you see `undefined`.

Secondly, when you are returning `rectRef`, you are essentially returning an object in which you later mutate when the `useEffect` in `useBoundingClientRect` runs. The data is returned before the `useEffect` is ran as it runs after the render cycle. Now when `useEffect` within the component runs, which is after the `useEffect` within the custom hook runs, the data is already there and has been updated at its reference by the previous `useEffect` and hence you see the correct data.

Lastly, if you return `rectRef.current` which is now a immutable value, the custom hook updates the value but at a new reference since the previous one was `null` and hence you don't see the change in your components `useEffect` method.

Comment: Thanks! I understand better the point about what's happening in the last part with the custom hook who return `rectRef.current`. Do you have a suggestion to achieve this ?

If I try to get the `getBoundingRectClient` on my ref in the useEffect of the App component, I can access this immediately but not if I externalise the logic in custom hook.